# How bq query can get 10000 rows?

Tags: google-bigquery

How can we get 10000 rows or more by **bq command line** ?

Here our code:

```
 bq --format=csv query "SELECT * FROM  [test.t1] limit 10000 "  > rs.txt
```

But returned data about 100 rows , we tried with "max_rows_per_request" but can't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We find the way to fix, here our code: (add **--max_rows**)

```
bq --format=csv query --max_rows=100000  "SELECT * FROM  [test.t1] limit 10000  "  > a.txt
```